# How do I check the entered quantity before the checkout phase in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce

How to check product quantity before checkout ?

I want to avoid the order if a required quantity is not reached.

Nota : I use Commerce Physical Product module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rules to change the quantity in a line item... so you could force the quantity up and output a system message. I don't know of a way to prevent them from checking out using rules.

So: Condition: Data Comparison: Line item: Product: SKU  equals XX
Condition: Data Comparison: Line Item: Quantity less than X
Action: System message explaining why we're increasing quantity
Action: Data Set Value: Set quantity to X+3

Update: [this strategy](http://drupal.org/node/1233508#comment-5135862) might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. My case seems more complicated but it's a good start. Thanks.

Comment: Please come back and write up your actual fix when you get it. Thanks!

Comment: Finally i use the solution of your link and i fork a condition of http://drupal.org/project/commerce_conditions in order to adapt to my own case. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Just created a similar rule. Product minimum quantity must be >=100 only for selected product.

Hope this helps...

[image: Config screenshot]